# How to set eslint env for a spesific folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, environment

I have a project that contains two environments: browser and service worker.
In `.eslintrc.js` file I have

```js
  env: {
   browser: true,
    serviceworker: true
  }
```

In `service-worker.js` file which could contain

```js
console.log(document);
```

I want `eslint` to show an error that `document` is not defined by the service worker.
In other words is it possible to set `serviceworker: true` to a specific path in my project?
If that is possible in vscode settings will be also fine.

Answer (score 1):

To apply an environment per-file, you can put this comment at the top of the file(s):

```
/* eslint-env serviceworker */
```

This is from the eslint documentation [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#using-configuration-comments).